# WiX: Where can I download the bootstrapper?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I'm running Visual Studio 2008 SP1, and I'm getting the following error when trying to compile my WiX projct:

> Could not find required file
>   'setup.bin' in 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Engine

I've got Windows Installer 3.0 and the Windows Platform SDK installed. I've got a Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A directory, but there is no Boostrapper directory. Where can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd146047.aspx) do you have installed? I installed [this one](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=150217) a few months back and it included the bootstrapper

Comment: I ran that, but it said I had everything installed. It turns out, the problem is that the bootstrapper directory is in Program Files (x86), but WiX is looking in Program Files. Any idea how to get WiX to look in the right place?

Comment: Try this: http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01750.html

Comment: This should allow you to specify a bootstrapper path: 
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm