# Where can I find the .NET bootstrapper files?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have created a setup project with VS2008 for a .NET Windows Forms application using .NET Framework 3.5.

But I want to create an installation with WiX 3.5. Since I have VS2008 installed, I expected I can use the instructions in the help section *How To: Install the .NET Framework Using a Bootstrapper*. Unfortunately this includes a reference to the directory

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\
```

that I cannot find on my PC although this should be present if VS2008 is installed. Should I find it somewhere on my PC or do I have to install this manually? Why should this be necessary?

What are other opportunities to automatically install the .NET framework when required?

**Edit:**
The WiX documentation describes the path for VS2005 on a 32 bit operating system. I found the boostrapper at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper
```

Comment: Have you tried "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper? The WiX article could have the path slightly wrong or be out of date.

Comment: @Peter: It is still a mysterium why a file search for 'Bootstrapper' on the whole disc did not found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few related questions to yours, check out [WiX: Where can I download the bootstrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509872/wix-where-can-i-download-the-bootstrapper)